# How basic can you get in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I like .net but I dislike the way pages are traditionally built in asp with its mvc model and whatnot.

Would it be possible to set up a project in such a way that no matter the page, every requests gets directed to a single function that provides me with all the request parameters, session and post data and I can just take it from there?

Comment: It's the "and whatnot" that makes it art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are after something like raw PHP. If that's the case, you are still free to go back to the dark days of ASP, forgoing webforms and MVC all together. The raw Request, Sever and Session variables are always there.

How basic can you get?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
 Dim ipa
 ipa = Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")
 Response.Write(ipa)
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create an MVC route for all URLs. In the action method you can pull anything from the `Request` object. This is very basic.

You can get more basic by using the `BeginRequest` event, either from the Global.asax or from an HTTP module. This event runs before any other processing has taken place.

I believe in ASP.NET 5 you can get even more "basic" by replacing just about everything.